# How to use a certificate (.cer) file to code siging in C#?

Tags: c#, certificate, code-signing

I have a .cer file (from Verisign) and an application in C# (VS 2010).
I don't have private key for this .cer file.
I want to use this .cer file to code signing the application.
Can anyone point me to right direction to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to have the private key first.

Comment: If I don't have it , how can I use this .cer file to code signing my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ZippyV already mentioned you will **need** the private key for signing Assemblies. Once you got it:

Use [SignTool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It's included in Windows SDK. Available free from Microsoft.

Depending the SDK Version you might get the new SignTool.exe with doesn't support /signwizard parameter.

Then you will need to call it:

`signtool sign /a /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" "%cd%\File.dll"`

(I recommand using a bat for easier signing of multiple files.)

If your SignTool support the signwizard parameter, use

`signtool /signwizard`

to get an easy to use wizard.